# Error: Cannot find module: Desktop\Udemy Courses\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'

Tags: react-native

I've created a new Project using react-native android and typescript and trying to run "npx react-native run-android" command. However I recieve this error

[image]

However, looking at the directory where bin.js is located, it seems that its present

[image]

Im not sure where the error lies but I apprecieate any help. Thanks